# Noncancelable Task that Restores Interruption Before Exit

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading some java thread interruption and I don't understand some stuff. Hope someone will explain me. So, it's done the following code

```
public Integer getInteger(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
    boolean interrupted = false;
    try {
        while (true) {
            try {
                return queue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                interrupted = true;
                // fall through and retry
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (interrupted)
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

The explanation is as follows :

> Activities that do not support cancellation but still call
>   interruptible blocking methods will have to **call them in a loop**,
>   retrying when interruption is detected. In this case, they should save
>   the interruption status locally and restore it just before returning,
>   as shown in listing. rather than immediately upon catching
>   InterruptedException. Setting the interrupted status too early could
>   result in an infinite loop, because most interruptible blocking
>   methods check the interrupted status on entry and throw
>   InterruptedException immediately if it is set. (Interruptible methods
>   usually poll for interruption before blocking or doing any significant
>   work, so as to be as responsive to interruption as possible.)

I don't understand why we should save the interrupted status locally.
I would be glad to hear some explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the design the method could not ever throw the InterruptedException. So it means we always expect take a value from the queue. But somebody could want the thread to be interrupted, that's why we have to save-restore the interrupted state after we have finally took a value from the queue.

So, the thread get finished only after taking a value from the queue.

**UPDATE:** Look into the `take()` method implementation. It has the following as the first statements:

```
public final void acquireInterruptibly(int arg) throws InterruptedException {
    if (Thread.interrupted())
        throw new InterruptedException();
...
}
```

Comment: ok, I understand that somebody could interrupt the thread running this method (and the method take would thorw an IE), but why not calling "Thread.currentThread().interrupt()" in  the catch block ?

Comment: "most interruptible blocking methods check the interrupted status on entry and throw InterruptedException immediately if it is set". It means if you set it in the catch block, it then loop again in the `take()` method and the method could exit immediately before doing any work (because you have set the interrupted state).

Comment: ok, understood, thanks, and, the last question, what should happen for the finally block to be reached ?

Comment: A finally block is always executed on exit from the try-block, regardless of an exception.

Comment: the finally block will be executed before the method returns, right ?

Comment: Right. More precisely - always when execution leaves `try{}` block

Comment: why we should call curentThread().interrupt(), as I understand, the thread's interrupted status will be already set (because of that the interrupted flag of the function is set), why setting it again ?

Comment: I know this, so the finally block act as a precaution, if someone cleared the flag ?

Comment: No, the take() method will always clearing it if flag is set, throwing the exception.

Comment: oh, right, blocking methods like sleep() / wait() / join() not only throw the IE Exception but also clear the int. status, forgot this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The loop will finish because of the statement

```
return queue.take();
```

This is not a tight loop even though it looks like one. It just blocks for one element and and returns as soon as it is available and retries if an interruption occurs.

Comment: how could be the finally block ever reached, only when we'l lhave some sort of uncaught exception ?

Comment: No, a finally block is always executed on exit from the try-block regardless of an exception.

Comment: `finally` block is *always* executed - irrespective of an exception being thrown or not - so in the above code , if an element is available , the method executes the finally block and returns immediately. It blocks if the element is not availble. and if an InterruptedException is thrown while blocking , it just retires for an element , but *eventually* , in *all* cases the finally block will be executed before the method returns.